# How can I increase weapon damage as much as possible in Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

How can I increase weapon damage as much as possible in Skyrim? I am playing on Xbox 360. Are there any glitches that I can exploit?

Comment: see http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Forum:Skyrim:Alchemy/Enchanting_Loop

Answer (score 39, accepted):

**Via Exploit:**

1. Get Yellow Mountain Flowers
2. Get Salt Piles
3. Buy Soul Gems
4. Create a Fortify Alchemy Item(s)
5. Equip the Fortify Alchemy Item(s)
6. Create & Drink a Fortify Restoration Potion
7. Remove the Fortify Alchemy Item(s)
8. Repeat Step 5 through 8 until the Fortify Alchemy Item has a ludicrous boost
9. Create & Drink a Potion of Fortify Enchanting
10. Enchant any item that has a damage component (ex: Absorb Health)
11. Have fun with your 6-figure+ damage output

Notes:

- You can do the same for Smithing Weapons/Armour and then use this exploit (but it's just so much damage that you don't even see the difference between having a glitched sword + glitched enchantment than just a glitch enchantment on a sword
- If you need to buy stuff from stores you can use the quicksave->kill->reload to refresh store inventory.
- You don't need a high level of enchanting nor alchemy, although one does make the process faster
- Don't go too overboard on the boost to the Fortify Items, as if they become too high the game may crash (~390000% is fine)
- [Recipe](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Fortify_Enchanting) of Potion of Fortify Enchanting

[Source (Youtube)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3oRQUrggnDk)

Comment: If you Fortify Blacksmithing high enough, you can destroy your weapon in one swing.  Best to keep that non-glitched.

Comment: If you're going to use a glitch to get unlimited damage, you might as well install a mod or use a console command.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft While I can't tell about mods available,OP stated that its the 360 version. As far as I know, there is no console on the console

Comment: This method is not a glitch; the game code is still working properly by allowing you to do this. This is called an (imbalance) *exploit*.

Comment: @TylerH You're right. I've edited the answer to fix that. Thank you

Comment: It's not necessary to kill a shopkeeper to reset their stock via saving and loading. Merely making them hostile will do the trick. However after doing a few cycles of this exploit, not killing them in one hit would be a challenge :P

Comment: @Mego Well, the extra damage comes all at once, but still, shopkeepers are surprisingly easy to 1 shot... I mean, I'm totally not doing sneak attacks :P

Comment: @TylerH From the description it sounds like the potion is intended to work only once and re-equipping the item gets around this restriction. That sounds like a bug.

Comment: @JollyJoker One gamer's bug is another Todd Howard's feature.

Comment: Should step 6 _really_ be a Fortify Restoration Potion? Fortify Alchemy Potion seems more reasonable, but maybe that is just inexperience. If it should be Restoration, maybe add a note about why for people like me.

Comment: @Odalrick, that's the point of exploit. Somewhy restoration potion increases the power of alchemy (and devs haven't fixed it).

Answer (score 17):

There are a couple of ways to increase weapon damage.

1. Get a better weapon, unless you are in end game and have some of the best weapons and materials available to, the next few options might not be worth it
2. Upgrade your weapon on the grindstone at a forge, your going to need some materials to do this, and the higher level you are in smithing, the greater the increase in damage.(Upgrade Ranks: Fine, Superior, Exquisite, Flawless, Epic, Legendary)
3. Put damage enchantments on it, this can increase the damage done by the weapon instantly by 10 damage depending on skill and spell, at level 100 enchanting you can put 2 damage enchantments on it, and with a grand soul gem, get even more damage out of it
4. Put poison potions on your weapons, these don't last long, but it will still increase your damage
5. Like one handed weapons, two handed, archery? Go to the specific skill tree of your favorite and put a few skill points there. The first point in each tree is a 20% increase in damage.

P.S. To get absolute MAX DAMAGE you're going to need enchanted equipment with fortify smithing on it and a potion of fortify smithing, as well as smithing at level 100 so you can max the damage increase on the grindstone

If you want more information on Smithing in Skyrim visit: http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Smithing_(Skyrim)

**NOTE:** In the early days of Skyrim there were a couple of damage exploits, but they were promptly patched, to my knowledge there aren't any damage exploits in the game today

Comment: This doesn't result in the max damage possible, just the max damage without glitches

Comment: @ Oak there are two parts to this question, He wants to know how to get max damage with and without exploits. And in my answer I added that to my knowledge there aren't any damage exploits that are still in the game

Answer (score 2):

Use a potion of smithy and have the respective perk for that material (under the Smithing Perk Tree), then upgrade it at a grindstone. Some alter blessings and items boost smithing. The higher your smithy, the better items will upgrade. No glitches required.

Answer (score 0):

This is the old restoration glitch . This method works the same way with boosting smithing,enchanting and alchemy . You can make any playstyle overpowered this way . It's time consuming but you use less perk points this way . You do have to be careful using this glitch though , you can lvl your character way to fast . Also a great way to make gold for training skills at higher levels .

Comment: When I use this glitch I make alchemy gear , enchanting gear and smithing gear . Super potions , super armor and super weapons . You can also make magic attacks casting free . I have learned though that you also need to improve weapon and armor skills .

Answer (score -2):

Get a full set of armor with fortify smiting. Then drink a potion of fortify smiting. After that build the strongest weapon and armor you can. hen upgrade them. When enchanting,Invest in enchanting perks, have a full armor set of fortify enchanting, and drink a potion of fortify enchanting. Then enchant the gear with the enchantment of your choice. After that invest in perks for either light armor, heavy armor and either one handed, archery, or two handed. There you go. For the best weapon do this with a stahlrim weapon, and when you enchant, use ultimate chaos damage and another frost enchantment.

Answer (score -2):

I don't think this method is significant after Oak's answer, however...

Eating vegetable soup gives you a steady supply of stamina.  Since you only need 1 stamina to power attack, vegetable soup allows you to do then non-stop.